# Can this subgroup be normal with these conditions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Suppose that $G$ is a group and $H$ is its subgroup such that for every subgroup $K$ of $G$, $HK$ is a subgroup.
Can we deduce that $H$ is normal?

(I know that the normality of either $H$ or $K$ is sufficient for $HK$ to be normal, but not a necessity.)

I feel like(!) there is a counter-example, but I can't find one.
Any help would be appreciated. :)

**Edit:** $HK = \{ hk: h \in H, k \in K \}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subgroups with that property are called *permutable* or *qusainormal*. There are examples of permutatble subgroups that are not normal, although they are always subnormal. An example is a non-central subgroup of order $p$ in a nonabelian group of order $p^3$ and exponent $p^2$ for an odd prime $p$. That is, the subgroup $\langle b \rangle$ in $\langle a,b \mid a^{p^2}=b^p=1, [a,b]=a^p \rangle$.

Comment: So, you mean the normality of $H$ can be deduced? How can it be proved?

Comment: I siad that normality could *not* be deduced and I gave an example toprove it.

Comment: Right; sorry, I didn't read your answer carefully. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

From the giving condition, for any $\;x\in G\;$ we have that

$$\;\langle x\rangle H\;\;\text{is a subgroup}\;\;\iff \langle x\rangle H=H\langle x\rangle$$

and this means, that $\;xH=Hx^k\;$, for some $\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$ , and this means $\;H\lhd G\;$ according to [this classical exercise](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_is_Normal_iff_Left_Cosets_are_Right_Cosets)

Comment: Hmm...I'm having some doubts about what I wrote above. Certainly, the left coset $\;xH:=\{xh\;:\;h\in H\}\;$ will be contained in the subgroup $\;H\langle x\rangle\;$ , but how can I be sure that if $\;xh=h'x^k\;$ , then for any other $\;h\neq h_1\in H\;$ I will have $\;xh_1=h''x^k\;$ WITH THE SAME $\;k\;$ ?? Interesting...perhaps someone of the experts can help here.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the definition of $HK$ in my question. Please  kindly take another look at the problem. :) @Joanpemo

Comment: @Behnaz Thank you, I know that definition: there is no other one in these cases. My doubt continues, though.